# No consigó añadir datos a mi array bidimensional

Tags: c#, array, string

```
class ArrayBiUsuarios
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
```

> El programa no está terminado aún. Mi programa consiste en un array bidimensional(4x2) que almacena la contraseña y el nombre de los usuarios

```
            //Array bidimensional de 4x2
            string[,] arrayUsuarios = new string[4, 2];

            IniciarUsuarios(arrayUsuarios);

        }
```

> Método que devuelve los datos de mis usuarios

```
        public static void IniciarUsuarios(string[,] arrayUsuarios)
        {
```

> Me da el siguiente error al ejecutar el programa (este error me aparece al agregar los datos de mi tercer usuario): System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' No consigo encontrar mi error

```
            //Almaceno mis usuarios y su contraseñas en el array bidimensional
            for (int i = 0; i <= arrayUsuarios.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Introduce el nombre del " + (i + 1) + "º usuario:");
                arrayUsuarios[i, 0] = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Introduce la contraseña del " + (i + 1) + "º usuario:"); 
                arrayUsuarios[i, 1] = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("");

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola, podrías decir por favor si la respuesta dada te fue util

Answer (score 0):

Ese error te da porque estás accediendo a una posición del arreglo que no es válida, en tu **ciclo for** tienes:

```
i <= arrayUsuarios.Length
```

Y debes poner:

```
i < arrayUsuarios.Length
```

O:

```
i <= arrayUsuarios.Length - 1
```

Ya que en **C#** la primera posición de un arreglo es la **0**, la **1** es la segunda, y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Hola, podrias decirme si esta solucion te sirvio